# Disguises can be too perfect. This means they can be ( ). Which is the best answer?

Tags: word-usage

Disguises can be too perfect. This means they can be (  ). Which is the best answer?

(a) perfect

(b) quite perfect

(c) more perfect than is convenient

(d) almost perfect

I saw the right answer is (c), but I do not know why other are wrong. Can you tell me the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question (presumably from a test, worksheet or quiz) is about understanding the adverb *too*. Each of the answers represents a different possible meaning for *too*:

1. Answer (a) suggests that it has effectively no meaning in that sentence
2. Answer (b) suggests that, applied to an adjective in that way, it means the same as *quite* - which is to say either "to a limited extent" or "to a great extent". *Quite* is quite an awkward word.
3. Answer (c) suggests that, applied to an adjective (let's call the adjective *X*) in that way, it means "more X than is convenient"
4. Answer (d) suggests that, applied to an adjective in that way, it means *almost*.

There are meaningless, surplus words in a lot of English phrases and sentences, but *too* is not one of them in this case. Here, it is an adverb of degree, and it has a specific meaning. **The other answers are wrong simply because *too* doesn't mean those things**.

It helps a little that the other two meaningful answers use a single word in place of *too*, while the right answer uses a phrase. Words can be defined with phrases, or with synonyms, but relatively fundamental words are more likely in practice to be defined with synonyms. However, they could have used a single word - they could have made the correct option read "*excessively* perfect".

*Too* doesn't always mean "more X than is convenient". It can mean "more X than some arbitrary threshold". It also has other meanings that aren't so interchangeable.

Comment: Can you help me comprehend the phrase 'more perfect than is convenient'?

Comment: You might alternatively say "more perfect than is desirable", "more perfect than is appropriate". Basically, so perfect that the perfection becomes a problem.

Comment: @Y.zeng For instance, somebody being questioned by the police on Halloween because they've made themselves look too much like a wanted criminal. I find the sentence somewhat contrived, as well as any scenario that would fit the answer. The given answer is quite . . .odd. But it's correct by the process of elimination. However, it's also based on something ungrammatical. Perfection doesn't have degrees. It is perfect or it isn't. So, it's not meaningful to say *more perfect*. Although it might be used in conversational speech, no grammar test should use it.

Comment: @JasonBassford You give me another view about the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford  But we can hear the phrase of ' too perfect' in many cases.

Comment: @Y.zeng Yes. That's another example of conversational speech, or informal use, that wouldn't normally be seen in formal writing—except in the case of certain forms or rhetoric, where the contradiction is used deliberately.

Comment: I don't know, I would personally think that a programme teaching English as a foreign language really should teach English as it is generally used. Things like that are used in formal contexts. You'll see it in academic literature. *Dead* might be considered the ultimate absolute adjective, but you'll come across that used relatively as well (though more often humourously). In American English, "a more perfect union" is a well-loved phrase.

Comment: @SamBC I can't find **more perfect than is convenient** in dictionaries. How to understand it?